# Akka HTTP client server idle timeouts are not working

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have written an API that takes couple of minutes to create a response. This apparently results in connection resets:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I have tried following timeout configurations from Akka HTTP but nothing seems to solve the above issue.

```
akka.http.server.idle-timeout = 600 s
akka.http.client.idle-timeout = 600 s

akka.http.server.request-timeout = 600 s
```

I suspect the issue is with the `idle-timeout`. But the above configuration doesn't seem to take any affect.

Could anyone please suggest what could be the issue?

I have tried a reverse scenario where i have set the `idle-timeout` to `5s` which is suppose to reset the connection but even that doesn't work. Not sure what is really wrong here. Could anyone please explain this behaviour and how can I fix it?

I have implemented a fully working example for anyone to try [here](https://github.com/iamsmkr/akka-http-starter-kit/tree/sleep).

application.conf

```
akka.http.server.idle-timeout = 5 s
akka.http.client.idle-timeout = 5 s

akka.http.server.request-timeout = 600 s

helloworld {
  http {
    interface = "127.0.0.1"
    port = "8066"
  }
}
```

Routes.scala

```
package com.codingkapoor.helloworld.http

import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import scala.concurrent.duration._

private[helloworld] trait Routes extends JsonSupport {

  implicit lazy val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5.minute)

  implicit def materializer: ActorMaterializer

  lazy val routes: Route = pathSingleSlash {
    get {
      Thread.sleep(180000)
      complete(StatusCodes.OK, "Hello World!")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two mistakes I found, fixing which solved the problem.

**Mistake 1**

I was forgetting to pass `appConf` as an argument while creating an instance of `ActorSystem`, without which `ActorSystem` was always getting created with  default akka configs. Hence always make sure to pass `appConf` while creating an instance of `ActorSystem` otherwise your akka configurations will never take effect.

**HelloWorld.Scala**

```
val appConf = RuntimeEnvironment.appConf

implicit val system = ActorSystem("helloworld", appConf)
```

**Mistake 2**

In the question I was putting `Thread.sleep` in the Route thread. This was causing `idle-timeout` to reach the logs only after sleep got over.

What I am trying to say is that when I was creating `ActorSystem` without `appConf`, default `idle-timeout` of `1 min` was supposed to come into play but because I was putting `Thread.sleep` of `3 min` in the route thread, the `idle-timeout` of `1 min` was getting logged only after `3 mins`.

```
# Despite idle-timeout being 1 min, the following exception was getting 
# logged only after 3 mins

Caused by: akka.http.impl.engine.HttpIdleTimeoutException: 
  HTTP idle-timeout encountered, no bytes passed in the last 1 minute.
  This is configurable by akka.http.[server|client].idle-timeout.
```

The best way to mimic delayed response is to complete the request with a future as shown below. Here I have set an `idle-timeout` of `4 mins` and `request-timeout` of `3 mins`. This results in request being served always! Hope that clarifies.

**application.conf**

```
akka.http.server.idle-timeout = 240000 s
akka.http.client.idle-timeout = 240000 s

akka.http.server.request-timeout = 600 s
```

**Routes.scala**

```
lazy val routes: Route = pathSingleSlash {
    get {
        complete {
            Future.unit.map(_ => Thread.sleep(180000))
                       .map(_ => StatusCodes.OK -> "Hello World!")
        }
    }
}
```

The whole idea is that if `idle-timeout` is greater than `request-timeout`, your requests at least have chance to get served otherwise they would simply get dropped!

```
idle timeout (10mins)    ------>

request timeout (5 mins) --->


idle timeout (1 min)     --->

request timeout (5 mins) ------>
```

You can find the working solution [here](https://github.com/iamsmkr/akka-http-starter-kit).